# in drupal 7, how can drupal link to another remote service, consume the data in the web service such as nodejs?

Tags: services

I am using the drupal 7 for my CMS server, at the same time, I have a nodejs based server, I need the drupal link to my nodejs server in order to make drupal consume the data in the nodejs based server, which will expose the restful service interface

Is there such a module that could link to the remote web service like nodejs rest, consume the data in the web service and expose the remote data as a view? and how to establish the authentication between drupal and nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the API from [Node.js project](http://drupal.org/project/nodejs). And build a module using it to consume your node.js server.

Comment: wow, good, is there any good tutorial for this project.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/mongodb could be used to share it fairly simply, you could also use services see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428014/steps-to-make-a-mobile-application-using-drupal-as-a-back-end-or-service

Both will provide you with JSON data basically and can easily be used in node and many other Web/Mobil applications.